# Daemon application gets an App-only access token with no Roles

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a JavaScript app that requires a user to login and hit a button then it runs a report, posts data to Excel, and sends an email. I want to automate this so a user does not have to log in and push a button.

I started with this project code: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-apponlytoken-rest-sample

I followed the instructions and am able to get an access token but then my api call fails with 401 unauthorized. As a test, I am trying to send an email as myself and I have the Application type Mail.Send permission granted by the company admin.

I have spent many hours reading docs and blogs but have not found a solution. This document summarizes best what I am troubleshooting: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2018/03/15/troubleshooting-assistance-with-microsoft-graph-api-development/.

The token I get back does not have any Roles in it as seen when I decode it with JWT. This is the only discrepancy I have found so far.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated. How can I ensure that my token has Roles defined or what else can I try? How is it that I can get a token successfully but can't use it for anything?

Thank you!

Comment: Which Graph Api are your calling and what application and delegated permissions it expects?

Comment: Please add the code you're using to retrieve the token and an example of a token you've received back to your question.

Comment: The Graph API I am using is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my.user.id>/sendMail but I am not using delegated permissions, I am using Application type permissions and they are approved by an IT Admin  => Mail.Send (Send mail as any user).

Comment: To get the token, I am using this code from GitHub: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-apponlytoken-rest-sample/blob/master/auth.js. I have tried as is for v1.0 tokens but have also tried to get v2.0 tokens and replace the resource with scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' but neither tokens have any Roles defined.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Node expert, so helping you out with a few pointers that might help.

Microsoft Graph has two types of permissions, [Delegated and Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference). So some things to know of and check..

1. Delegated permissions require a user to be present, they would show up in the *scp* claim in the access token. These are obtained by web applications using the [implicit_grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) flow, [Authorization code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) (usually).
2. Application Permissions, require an admin to consent and will be provided to you in the *roles* claim in the [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens). This requires, the app to obtain an access token via the [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) grant. Note that, these are also present when the user is assigned a role as explained in [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles), but this scenario might not be applicable for in your case.

Does you app has the grant provided as you expect? You can check these via the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) using the following two rest calls. There would be a [OAuth2PermissionGrant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-beta) entry with the expected role in it.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/OAuth2PermissionGrants
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/kalyankrishna.net/OAuth2PermissionGrants

It'd help more if you can explain the flow that you have been using to obtain the access token. For example, the [implicit_grant_flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) does not work with application permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem had to do with the endpoint and my tenant. I had been using the common tenant make api calls for tokens because that is what was listed in AzureAD for my app. I found that for the Application client permissions I must use my specific tenant id like 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/**tenant_id**/oauth2/token' when getting tokens with the proper roles.